# How to make an inherited class parcelable without common constructor?

Tags: kotlin

I get following error for `PhoneAppItem`:

> Parcelable should have primary constructor

How can I solve this? I have a base class with constructors that don't share a basic constructor, so how can I extend such a class and make it parcelable in kotlin?

**Ideas**

- add the primary constructor => then I get the exception, that my secondary constructors in `PhoneAppItem` do not call the primary constructor, IDE says following:

> primary constructor call expected

**Code**

Here's the basic barebone code (*I have more than 2 simple constructors!!*) that creates this error:

```
abstract class AbstractPhoneAppItem : Parcelable {
    constructor() {

    }
    constructor(packageName: String?) {
        this.packageName = packageName
    }   
}


@Parcelize
class PhoneAppItem : AbstractPhoneAppItem {
    constructor() : super()
    constructor(packageName: String?) : super(packageName)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Kotlin are you using? Have you tried:

```
abstract class AbstractPhoneAppItem(): Parcelable {
    private var packageName: String? = null

    constructor(packageName: String?): this() {
        this.packageName = packageName
    }   
}


@Parcelize
class PhoneAppItem : AbstractPhoneAppItem {
    constructor() : super()
    constructor(packageName: String?) : super(packageName)
}
```

Comment: I don't want to call `this` for the second constructor, my base class has an independent constructor that I want to call! Otherwise this of course works, but it skips the base class constructor with the same parameters as the one in the inherited class

Comment: No, in my code the inherited class constructors call corresponding base class constructors, and in the base class construcor with parameter calls constructor without one.

Comment: Which properties do you expect code generated by `@Parcelize` to read from/write to the parcel?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a primary constructor with an optional parameter:

```
abstract class AbstractPhoneAppItem (var packageName: String? = null) : Parcelable {
}
```

This way, you can use it without any params (so your packageName is null, or the default value you want) or use it with a parameter. Your item class then can call the superclass's primary constructor.

Comment: My constructor logic does not allow this, I do different things in different constructors and this logic can't be put into a single constructor without adding additional parameters

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use a [custom parceler](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/extensions/android-parcelable.md#custom-parcelables):

```
@Parcelize
class PhoneAppItem : AbstractPhoneAppItem {
    constructor() : super()
    constructor(packageName: String?) : super(packageName)

    companion object : Parceler<PhoneAppItem> {
        // modify logic to taste
        override fun PhoneAppItem.writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
            parcel.writeString(packageName)
        }

        override fun create(parcel: Parcel): PhoneAppItem {
            return PhoneAppItem(parcel.readString())
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise, `@Parcelize` really needs a primary constructor to know what to do.

Comment: Still complains here the lack of the primary constructor